# CNN for Image similiarity

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, feature-extraction

I'm currently working on a machine learning task where the goal is to decide to which of two pictures the food in a third picture tastes more similar. So for each sample we have 3 pictures: A, B and C. The goal is the predict 1 if the food depicted in A tastes more similar to the one depicted in B, and 0 if it tastes more like the one depicted in C. For training I was provided with 10 0000 samples where in each sample the food depicted in A and B taste similar, while the one depicted in C tastes different.

Just one example of a training sample:

- A: piece of cake with icecream on top
- B: some scoops of icecream
- C: broccoli

My question is how to tackle the problem. I could use a pretrained CNN and fine tune it to my task, but I don't quite get what the objective would be. How could I use my training data to train a model? As for all the training data the label would be a '1', (first two images of sample are more similar than the first and the third) should I shuffle a couple of the samples, e.g. exchange image B and C such that the label would be '0'?
Or should I completely discard the training data and just use a CNN to extract a feature vector for each image and then based upon the similarity of this vector judge which images are more similiar?

Comment: It seems to me that keywords to start googling for you are siamese networks and triplet loss.

Comment: Thanks looks promising at a first glance

Comment: https://medium.com/mlreview/how-to-apply-distance-metric-learning-for-street-to-shop-problem-d21247723d2a